# How to cache node_modules for unchanged package.json during yarn / npm install during docker build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have a Dockerfile for a node application looking like this:

```
FROM node:8.3
ENV TERM=xterm-color NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn PATH="$PATH:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/"
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-platform --ignore-engines --quiet && tsc && webpack
CMD ["node", "/usr/src/app/server"]
```

Yet this means that on *every* change to the sourcetree, the layer with `RUN yarn install ...` will be invalidated and run again.

As yarn install by itself takes about 80s, the built is unnecessarily slowed down even if only a `Readme.md` changed.

I want to use only run `yarn install` once either the package.json or `yarn.lock` changes.

This question would also apply to npm and its packlage

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the package.json and the appropriate lock file and run the intallation in a temp folder. After adding the source, you can mv the node_modules and files into the main app folder.

Here's an example if using `yarn install`.

```
FROM node:8.3
ENV TERM=xterm-color NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn PATH="$PATH:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/"
VOLUME ["/logs"]
WORKDIR /tmp/node
ADD package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-platform --ignore-engines --quiet
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN mv /tmp/node/* ./ && tsc && webpack
CMD ["node", "/usr/src/app/server"]
```

A quick metric using `time` return these output for the tweaked Dockerfile on `docker build .`:

- On source file change:

  - 0m34.084s
- On yarn.lock change:

  - 2m22.774s

For npm, you would need, depending on your version, need to add either

- `npm-shrinkwrap.json`
- `package-lock.json`

as insted of the `yarn.lock` file.